# In tests - How do I identify different instances of the same child component?

Tags: angular

I have a form with two instances of the same component, similar to the "From Date" - "To Date" scenario.

At the moment I use:

```
const myComponents = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(MyComponent))
const firstComponent = myComponents[0]
const secondComponent = myComponents[1]
```

Is there a better way, than relying on the index to identify each of the components?
something like:

```
const firstComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(???)
const secondComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(???)
```

Comment: Use ViewChildren https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren or ViewChild:https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form control in angular than you can
directly select the angular component by

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateTaskComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;

and in test case you can do like
component.formGroup
.get('endDateControl')

Comment: hmm, my component hasn't got formGroup property. I think it is because it is a Template Form.